# How many group homomorphisms between $\mathbb Z_{15}$ and $\mathbb Z_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

I need to show that if
$$f: \mathbb Z_{15} \to \mathbb Z_8$$
then $f \equiv 0$

I have found that the number of homomorphisms between $\mathbb Z_n$ and $\mathbb Z_m$ is the $\gcd(n,m)$

Thus the $\gcd(15,8)=1$ meaning that the trivial homomorphism is the only homomorphism.

How can I show that the number of homomorphisms between $\mathbb Z_n$ and $\mathbb Z_m$ is indeed $\gcd(n,m)$?

Comment: Hint:$order( f(a))$ should divide 15 for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{15} $

Comment: The hint given is valid in general. You should try to prove it in order to understand the number of homorphisms between two groups.

Comment: The number of homomorphisms "between" $\mathbb Z_m$ and $\mathbb Z_n$ is the number of homomorphisms $f:\mathbb Z_m\to\mathbb Z_n$ plus the number of homomorphisms $g:\mathbb Z_n\to\mathbb Z_m.$ (Assuming $m\ne n.$)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused by what is meant by the hint, how will this show the theorem is true?